# Arraylist is adding objects twice

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a strange problem with arraylist. I add objects to arraylist in for loop, everything is working fine except arraylist add method. It seems like my list is adding each object twice but I can't find a reason of this.
Here is my code

```
private void generateCitizens()
{
    int counter = Constants.CITIZENS_NUMBER;
    Random r = new Random(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    while(counter > 0)
    {
        int x = r.nextInt(Constants.TILES_IN_WIDTH) + 1;
        int y = r.nextInt(Constants.TILES_IN_HEIGHT) + 1;

        if(map.collisionTable[y][x] == 2)
        {
            Citizen c = new Citizen(x, y, citizenTexture.deepCopy(), map);
            citizensList.add(c);
            Log.i("Citizens count", String.valueOf(citizensList.size()));
            scene.attachChild(c);
            counter--;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<citizensList.size(); i++)
    {
        Log.i("Citizen - ", citizensList.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

Constants.CITIZENS_NUMBER is 15 in this case and this is what I got in logs

> 05-10 15:13:36.801: I/Citizens count(3237): 2
>   05-10 15:13:36.801: I/Citizens count(3237): 4
>   05-10 15:13:36.801: I/Citizens count(3237): 6
>   05-10 15:13:36.801: I/Citizens count(3237): 8
>   05-10 15:13:36.801: I/Citizens count(3237): 10
>   05-10 15:13:36.811: I/Citizens count(3237): 12
>   05-10 15:13:36.811: I/Citizens count(3237): 14
>   05-10 15:13:36.811: I/Citizens count(3237): 16
>   05-10 15:13:36.811: I/Citizens count(3237): 18
>   05-10 15:13:36.821: I/Citizens count(3237): 20
>   05-10 15:13:36.821: I/Citizens count(3237): 22
>   05-10 15:13:36.821: I/Citizens count(3237): 24
>   05-10 15:13:36.821: I/Citizens count(3237): 26
>   05-10 15:13:36.831: I/Citizens count(3237): 28
>   05-10 15:13:36.831: I/Citizens count(3237): 30
>   05-10 15:13:36.831: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@40535d40
>   05-10 15:13:36.831: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@40535d40
>   05-10 15:13:36.831: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@40537318
>   05-10 15:13:36.831: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@40537318
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@40514688
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@40514688
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@40799fe8
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@40799fe8
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@4079c308
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@4079c308
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@4079abd8
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@4079abd8
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@4079b4a0
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@4079b4a0
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba160
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba160
>   05-10 15:13:36.841: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba230
>   05-10 15:13:36.851: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba230
>   05-10 15:13:36.851: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba300
>   05-10 15:13:36.861: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba300
>   05-10 15:13:36.861: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba3d0
>   05-10 15:13:36.861: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba3d0
>   05-10 15:13:36.861: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba4a0
>   05-10 15:13:36.861: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407ba4a0
>   05-10 15:13:36.861: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407bac18
>   05-10 15:13:36.861: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407bac18
>   05-10 15:13:36.871: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407bb3f0
>   05-10 15:13:36.871: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407bb3f0
>   05-10 15:13:36.871: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407bbc80
>   05-10 15:13:36.871: I/Citizen -(3237): com.lpp.towndefence.Citizen@407bbc80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you subclass the `List` class ?

May `new Citizen` add itself to the list ? Or the `attachChild` method on scene ?

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, that's common mistake. Try to define each object/entity role to avoid these mistakes.